# how can i get mysql to return an array that is inside JSON

Tags: mysql, json

im trying to return a product that can have three images per product.
something like this:

```
{
product_id: 1,
product_name:"test",
category_id_fk: 1,
product_price: 12,
product_desc:"lorem-ipsum",
product_images:[path1, path2, path3]
}
```

Here is what i have got so far,

```
create table product(
product_id serial not null primary key,
category_id_fk int not null references category(category_id) ,
product_image_fk int not null references product_images(product_images_id),
product_name varchar(50) not null,
product_price int not null,
product_desc varchar(200) not null);

create table product_images(
product_images_id serial not null primary key,
product_image_one varchar(150) not null,
product_image_two varchar(150) not null,
product_image_three varchar(150) not null);
```

this is the query im using for the product details page

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id_fk = ?  AND product_id = ?;
```

Im new to SQL and have been really having a tough time with this specifically, would
appreciate it a lot if anyone could explain to me what im doing wrong or if you have any tips for me.

Comment: Provide INSERT INTO with sample data which must result in shown desired JSON.

Comment: Normally it is not the databases task to create a JSON string. Even if it is possible with some hacks this should normally be done by your backend code. You should change the design of the image table to have only one image per row only.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff *Normally it is not the databases task to create a JSON string.* ?? Normally data processing is DBMS task. If the result of processing must be in JSON format then DBMS must form JSON. MySQL have all needed instruments for this task.

Comment: PS. `column_fk int not null references table (column_id)` **DOES NOT CREATE FOREIGN KEY !!!** - `references` clause is parsed but ignored. For to create foreing key relation use separate FK definition.

Comment: @Akina I don’t like this new wave to put program Logik to the DBMS. This reduces your flexibility in changing the database type and it increases the need of hardware performance for the dB server. For me a database should be a data provider not more and not less. But I know I am far alone with this opinion :)

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I take it as "I will ignore well-programmed and tuned DBMS procedures and will use my program - of course I can do this better". *This reduces your flexibility in changing the database type* This is extremely rare operation. And most part of SQL code can be easily adopted to another SQL dialect. *it increases the need of hardware performance for the dB server.* ... but decreases the same on the client side. Totally the performance increase is more often total result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what programming language you are using, but in this case I assume you are using a programming language like PHP as a REST API provider because you are using prepared statements
Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `product_images` `pi` LEFT JOIN `product` `p`
ON `pi`.`product_images_id` = `p`.`product_image_fk` WHERE
`p`.`product_id` = ? AND `p`.`category_id_fk` = ?
```

Then on your PHP scripts you can make it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product_images` `pi` LEFT JOIN `product` `p`
ON `pi`.`product_images_id` = `p`.`product_image_fk` WHERE
`p`.`product_id` = ? AND `p`.`category_id_fk` = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $productId, $categoryId);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
$jsonArray = [
    "product_id" => $row["product_id"],
    "product_name" => $row["product_name"],
    "category_id_fk" => $row["category_id_fk"],
    "product_price" => $row["product_price"],
    "product_desc" => $row["product_desc"],
    "product_images" => [$row["product_image_one"], $row["product_image_two"], $row["product_image_three"]]
];
$expectedJson = json_encode($jsonArray);
```

And you can do whatever you want to the json maybe by storing it on the json file or to print it as http response

Comment: Never use select *

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 'product_id', p.product_id,
                    'product_name', p.product_name,
                    'category_id_fk', p.category_id_fk,
                    'product_price', p.product_price,
                    'product_desc', p.product_desc,
                    'product_images', JSON_ARRAY(pi.product_image_one,
                                                 pi.product_image_two,
                                                 pi.product_image_three) ) output
FROM product p
JOIN product_images pi ON p.product_image_fk = pi.product_images_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16f3a1fe3619c6c3601983d4c00de07d